# Búsqueda de objetos en ArrayList

Tags: java

Tengo un **ArrayList** que lleno con distintos vehículos: "Coche", "Camion", "Moto", etc. Cada uno es un objeto independiente con sus respectivos atributos.

Ahora, las motos están en oferta, por lo que necesito buscar todas las motos en el array para mostrarlas.

```
public void mostrarOfertas() {

    for(int i=0; i<vehiculos.size(); i++) {
        if(vehiculos.get(i) ==> Es una moto) {
            System.out.println(c.patente+" Esta en oferta");
        }
    }
}
```

Mi clase Vehiculo, de la cual heredan el resto de vehículos como "Moto".

```
public class Vehiculo implements EnPromocion{

private double precio;
protected int pasajeros;
protected int pasajerosMax;
protected int dias;
protected String patente;   

public Vehiculo(int pasajerosMax, String patente){
    this.pasajerosMax=pasajerosMax;
    this.patente=patente;
}   

public double getPrecio() {
    return calcularPrecio(1,1);
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getPatente() {
    return patente;
}

public void setPatente(String patente) {
    this.patente = patente;
}

public int getPasajeros() {
    return pasajeros;
}

public void setPasajeros(int pasajeros) {
    this.pasajeros = pasajeros;
}

public double calcularPrecio(int dias, int pasajeros){
    return 900*dias;
}

@Override
public double precioDePromocion(int pasajeros) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Tienes una clase **Vehiculo** con una atributo **tipo** o algo así? Deberías poner el código necesario para generar los objetos que guardas en el **ArrayList**, esto permitiría reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Es correcto lo que te dice @Orici, y si usas Java 8, lo podrás hacer muy fácilmente usando expresiones lambda, invocando el método `getTipo()`  de tu clase `Vehiculo` y comparándolo.

Comment: Agregué mi clase Vehiculo a la pregunta, y no, no tengo un atributo tipo.

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta es cómo saber si **vehiculos.get(i)** es un objeto **moto**.

Comment: ocupa enum, más abajo te puse un código que te puede servir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP comentó:

> La pregunta es cómo saber si `vehiculos.get(i)` es un objeto `moto`

También mencionas:

> Mi clase Vehiculo, de la cual **heredan** el resto de vehículos como "Moto".

Siendo que `Moto` hereda de `Vehiculo`, quiere decir que puedes usar el operador `instanceof` para determinar si un vehículo es una moto:

```
if(vehiculos.get(i) instanceof Moto) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto

Enum

```
 public enum TipoVehiculo {
Coche, Camion, Moto;
}
```

Clase vehículos

```
import java.util.List;
public class Vehiculos {

private TipoVehiculo tipo;
private double precio;
protected int pasajeros;
protected int pasajerosMax;
protected int dias;
protected String patente;

public Vehiculos(int pasajerosMax, String patente) {
    this.pasajerosMax = pasajerosMax;
    this.patente = patente;
}

public TipoVehiculo getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(TipoVehiculo tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return calcularPrecio(1, 1);
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getPatente() {
    return patente;
}

public void setPatente(String patente) {
    this.patente = patente;
}

public int getPasajeros() {
    return pasajeros;
}

public void setPasajeros(int pasajeros) {
    this.pasajeros = pasajeros;
}

public double calcularPrecio(int dias, int pasajeros) {
    return 900 * dias;
}


public double precioDePromocion(int pasajeros) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void mostrarOfertas(List<Vehiculos> listavehiculos) {
    TipoVehiculo tipoVehi = null;
    for (Vehiculos ve:listavehiculos) {
        if (ve.getTipo() == tipoVehi.Moto) {
        System.out.println(ve.getPatente() + " Esta en oferta");
        }
    }
}
```

}